# No module named 'xlrd' when xlrd module is installed

Tags: python, import, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook in an environment, and when I try to use `xlrd` module I get "`No module named 'xlrd`". I checked others Stack Overflow posts and I installed the module xlrd using the command  `pip3 install xlrd`. but still it continues to throw me the error `No module named 'xlrd`.

I tried again to install may be something went wrong and I get `Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` which I believe it's ok. Is it possible that I have to update my environment in order to use the new installs? If so how do I do it?

Comment: what is the value of  `sys.path`?

Comment: which one is your kernel, `python 2x` or `python 3x` ?

Comment: @amin python is not kernel